# Asp.net Multi Tenancy implementation on existing solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC solution, Entity Framework code first, which has dozens of database tables all designed around a single company using the solution.

The requirement has come up to allow multiple companies to use the solution, so what we have done is add "CompanyID" as a column to all database tables and set a default value.  There is a company table with the various company names and CompanyID's.  On login the user selects the company they are logging in as which stores the CompanyID in the session.

At the moment every Entity Framework call now has to be updated to include the CompanyID, for example when selecting Employees I am doing:

```
List<Employee> employees = db.Employees.Where(x => x.CompanyID = Session.CompanyID).ToList();
```

As you can see it will be tedious to do this on thousands of calls to the db.  Any update, save, and fetch has to change.

Surely I am doing it the long way and there is a way at runtime, globally to append all DB calls to include the CompanyID stored in the logged in users Session?  Something that dynamically appends the CompanyID when fetching values or storing etc?  Perhaps a package I can use to do this task at runtime?

Comment: For this scenario, why don't you use one database per company? There is probably no overlap, so why put it all in one database? It's easier to set the connectionstring (based on url, claim or something) instead..

Comment: If you go the "database per company" route, make sure you have a plan for how to handle managing all the databases, to keep their schema the same, update them, manage backups etc. It took us a while to develop the tooling to do it, but my company now has 9K databases with the same schema, and it's not as big a headache as you might think. Without the tooling, it'd be a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for comments, the reason why I can't do one database per company is because companies will be created on the fly, once launched my client will have an interface to add companies and users, which should allow a company ability to log in immediately.  This would require a developer to create the database every time not so?

Comment: @mason If that's the case then I could do that and on login choose the connection string to use?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's up to your app to work in whatever way is best. So decide what your needs are and what design might best suit those needs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no need to add `CompanyID` to EVERY table in the database. I would select just "root" tables/entities for that. For example, `Employee` or `Department` clearly sounds like a many-to-one relationship with a company - so adding `CompanyID` there sounds right. But, for example, `EmployeeEquipment` which is a many-to-one relationship with `Employee` does not have to have `CompanyID` column since it can be filtered by the joined `Employee` table.

Regarding your request to filter by CompanyID globally, I'm not aware of anything that can do that per request. There are global filters for Entity Framework, but I'm not sure how you can apply them per-request. Take a look on [`.HasQueryFilter()` during model creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) if you are using Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately dozens of tables/models would need updating to include the CompanyID as many of them fetch records that aren't related to one individual logged in employee, it would still require hundreds of calls to be modified to include an identifier per company.  The logged in user won't be limited to only see records relating to them but rather company wide.